# Is there an Entity Frame Library or extension that handles Json functions with linq?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sql-server-2016

I would like to complete the following code using Entity Framework in .Net Core to query a JSON object from my API where my API is linked to MS SQL Server 2016. I don't want to take in the entire JSON and query from my backend, I want SQL to handle the querying using the MS JSON Functions and return only the queried information.

Something along the lines of:

```
var queryList = _context.myTable.Select(r => JSON_QUERY(r.myJsonColumn, '$.info')).ToList();
```

and

```
var valueList = _context.myTable.Select(r => JSON_VALUE(r.myJsonColumn, '$.info')).ToList();
```

I would like to do this without using a string inside the select statement and without creating my own function.

Overall I want a **library** where I can use **JSON_VALUE, JSON_QUERY, ISJSON and JSON_MODIFY** with my entity framework and linq.

Comment: can you explain why you want to do this?  Seems like the functionality could all be done client-side using whatever language you like.

Comment: I would like to utilize querying on the server side because we may have 100s/1000s of SQL stored Json files i want filtered before returning to the back end to hopefully improve performance on my api.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is why you want to store as Json when you seem to need the functionality of a database.

Comment: because i want to create dynamic metadata for a user where each user can create any field and any number of fields and store it with a key value object -> json but need to store and query everything hence sql db but using EF to query without creating some absurd select string

Comment: you could create a table for each unique dataset I guess... but I would think at some point you'd need to know what the data is... so mapping it to a standard format? Short answer is that I would think you'd want to create a database at some point and you need to know the structure of that.  JSON is just an array so I believe you'd have to load it into memory to perform SQL like statements on it.  (though maybe you could stream in chunks?)

Comment: I ended up looking at three possible solutions: 1. not using EF and just filtering normally using a key value 2. using decision tree https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/52017204/expression-tree-to-sql-with-ef-core         3. calling a stored sql procedure with the FromSql function provided in the  EF relational extension library.

Comment: you still need to know what to use for the key, no?  Or is the key value a sort of blind guess input?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on .NET EF 7.

1. Make EF understand the JSON_VALUE function:

```
public static class DbFunction
{
  public static string JsonValue(string column, [NotParameterized] string path) => throw new NotSupportedException();

  public static void AddJsonValueDbFunction(this ModelBuilder builder)
  {
    builder
      .HasDbFunction(typeof(DbFunction).GetMethod(nameof(JsonValue))!)
      .HasTranslation(args => new SqlFunctionExpression(
        functionName: "JSON_VALUE",
        arguments: args,
        nullable: true,
        argumentsPropagateNullability: new bool[] { false, false },
        type: typeof(string),
        typeMapping: null
      ));
  }
}
```

2. Register new 'DbFunction.JsonValue' EF Function in DbContext

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
  // ...

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {
    // Add JSON_VALUE database function support
    builder.AddJsonValueDbFunction();

    // ...
  }
}
```

3. Use the 'JsonValue' in Select or Where LINQ queries

```
// Get db context
using var db = _dbFactory.CreateDbContext();

// Get ABCs
var abcs = await db.ABCs
  .AsNoTracking()
  .Select(a => new
  {
    a.Id,
    PlusCode = DbFunction.JsonValue(a.JsonColumn, "$.plusCode"),
    State = DbFunction.JsonValue(a.JsonColumn, "$.state")
  })
  .Where(a => DbFunction.JsonValue(a.JsonColumn, "$.state") == "NY"
  .ToListAsync();
```